# Is it possible to share CARTO datasets with password?

Tags: javascript, carto, carto-js

It's my understanding that only CARTO maps can be password-protected, not datasets. I'm currently using the datasets like so:

```
const source = new carto.source.Dataset(dataset);
const style = new carto.style.CartoCSS(cartoLayerCss);
const layer = new carto.layer.Layer(source, style, {
  ...
});

this.client
      .addLayer(layer)
      .then(() => {
         ...
}
```

Am I forced to

1. make the dataset private
2. create a map out of it
3. set a password on that map and
4. bind the pw-protected map via `vis.json`?

Answer (score 1):

CARTO Builder and Editor maps can be shared with password. CARTO datasets "can be shared" [using tokens with the Auth API](https://carto.com/developers/auth-api/guides/CARTO-Authorization/) (`vis.json` does not work with CARTO.js v4).

Comment: Thanks but I don't wanna "share" them per se -- I intend to display them on google maps.

Comment: Then you need to play with the Auth API somehow. Maybe you can use tokens as pwds...

Comment: No cleaner way?

Comment: I don't know. Ask CARTO support.

Comment: k, thanks for your answer.